# Which layout will use a 10,1" 1024x600 tablet?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-layout

I want to make sure that devices with 10,1" and 1024x600 under 2.1/2.2(e.g. Archos 101) are using the correct layout.

Are they large and ldpi?

Also, how can I simulate them using the android emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, the choices of screen size and screen density are up to the manufacturer. Hence, nobody here can answer you definitively.

A 10.1" diagonal screen should be `large` and *probably* should be `ldpi`, though it is possible it will be declared `mdpi` based upon the apparent density given the distance one would typically hold a 10.1" tablet from one's face.

Bear in mind that ARCHOS' devices do not ship with the Android Market AFAIK, and hence do not necessarily pass the various compatibility tests. As a result, ARCHOS could do all sorts of stuff that would be unexpected.

> Also, how can I simulate them using the android emulator?

The Android SDK is not well-suited for testing a 10.1" LCD at this time. I would expect better instructions and support for such sizes in Android 3.0.

For now, set the resolution and density for the AVD when you create it. In this case, you would want to specify 120dpi (`ldpi`) for the density. Android should put it in the `large` screen size bucket for you, given those values. Leastways, that basic approach works for getting `large` WVGA devices.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought.. I'll define a layout-large-ldpi just in case..